# When I put number in array size The project work fine but when i put int subNo give me error

Tags: java, arrays

I am new in this field.

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Subject {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        System.out.println("Please Enter Subject No");
        subNo =scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Subject No Is : " + subNo);


        for (int i = 0; i < subNo; i++) {

            System.out.println("Please Enter Subject Name " + (i + 1));
            subName[i] = scan.next();

        }
    }

    public static int subNo;

    public static String[] subName = new String [subNo] ;
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

}
```

Comment: Is there a question here that I'm missing?

Comment: `public static String[] subName = new String [subNo] ;` - `subNo` is `0` at this statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize your array after you read `subNo` :

```
public static String[] subName;//<---------------not initialize it here
static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Please Enter Subject No");
    subNo = scan.nextInt();
    subName = new String[subNo];//<------------------initialize it here
    System.out.println("Subject No Is : " + subNo);
```

Because when you run your program your array will be inisialize with the static `subNo` and not with the new one in your main

Comment: Thanks for you reply YCF_L , it's helping me and i learn Something new

Comment: you are welcome @Hemasharshar enjoy with java good luck (ya akhi al karim) ;)

Answer (score 0):

You must define the `subName` variable after of `subNo` variable, because this will be assigned after entering a value, for example:

```
public static int subNo;
static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please Enter Subject No");
    subNo = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Subject No Is : " + subNo);

    String[] subName = new String[subNo];

    for (int i = 0; i < subNo; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please Enter Subject Name " + (i + 1));
        subName[i] = scan.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply JUAN CALVOPINA M , your info is helpful for me